# Flash Air 3.2 FileStream resulting 'undefined'

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working with Flash Air 3.2 (Old, I know) and I'm trying to start off by reading a text file using FileStream. The code I have finds the file, and I've put text in the file, but whenever I try to run the code it returns 'undefined'. Here's my code:

```
import flash.filesystem.*
import flash.net.*
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.events.*

var myFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt"); 
var myFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
myFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
myFileStream.openAsync(myFile, FileMode.READ); 
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 

function completeHandler(event:Event):void  
{ 
    myFileStream.readBytes(bytes, 0, myFileStream.bytesAvailable); 
    trace(myFileStream.readBytes(bytes, 0, myFileStream.bytesAvailable));
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get undefined because the `readBytes` method of a [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readBytes()) has a return type of `void`.   The bytes read from that method get put into the byte array you pass to it rather than being returned directly from the method.

```
myFileStream.readBytes(bytes, 0, myFileStream.bytesAvailable); //this returns void/undefined by design regardless of the contents of bytes
trace(bytes); //this will trace the byte array object that was populated with the above line
```

If you're just looking to read a text file, you should be able to do the shortcut method:

```
myFileStream.readUTF();
```